# Alias command from terminal that opens a new terminal on a specific folder

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I have this command already working in my .bash_profile:

```
alias mysite='cd /Applications/sites/mysite;pwd; php artisan serve --port=9000 | open http://localhost:9000 | open -a Finder ./'
```

So it:

- CD's into the folder
- Starts artisan serve
- Opens a new browser window at that address
- Opens a new Finder window at that same location

---

What i would like it to do, is add a new command to do something like:

```
open -a Terminal cd /Applications/sites/mysite
```

So it opens a new Terminal window, and cd's int that new terminal window to the same folder.

Is it possible? I've tried this:

```
alias mysite='cd /Applications/sites/mysite;pwd; php artisan serve --port=9000 | open http://localhost:9000 | open -a Finder ./ | open -a Terminal cd /Applications/sites/mysite'
```

But i can't make it work. It does everything as in the first example but it never opens the new terminal window :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the last part of your command (`open -a Terminal cd /Applications/sites/mysite`) works, as the argument is not passed to be executed as a command, see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/989349/2429404).

One workaround is to use AppleScript for last part:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd /Applications/sites/mysite"'
```

To include this in your alias definition, make sure all single/double quotes match and escape where necessary:

```
alias mysite='cd /Applications/sites/mysite; pwd; php artisan serve --port=9000 | open http://localhost:9000 | open -a Finder ./ | osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd /Applications/sites/mysite\""'
```

Does that work for you?